# Find when a page finished loading in xamarin.forms prism

Tags: xamarin.forms, prism, pageload, page-lifecycle

I am trying to create an optimized Event Tracker for my Xamarin.forms prism application. I would like to know whether there is any method to find out when the page load is finished. If someone could help me, please save my time.

Comment: `OnAppearing` is what you are looking for on a `ContentPage`

Comment: @FreakyAli `OnAppearing()` is called when the page is about to become visible. Not sure if that's what the OP wants, but it's probably the closest thing anyway. There's not actual `Loaded` event, unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

You can implement page loading methods for different platforms through custom renderer.

For iOS, override the viewDidLoad method, ViewDidLoad(Called after the controller's view is loaded into memory.)

```
[assembly:ExportRenderer (typeof(ContentPage), typeof(MyRenderer))]
namespace Demo.iOS
{
    public class MyRenderer : PageRenderer
    {

        protected override void OnElementChanged(VisualElementChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnElementChanged(e);
        }
        public override void ViewDidLoad()
        {
            base.ViewDidLoad();
        }
    }
}
```

For Android, rewrite the OnAttachedToWindow method, OnAttachedToWindow(This is called when the view is attached to a window.)

```
[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(ContentPage), typeof(MyRenderer))]
namespace Demo.Droid
{
    public class MyRenderer : PageRenderer
    {
        public MyPageRenderer(Context context) : base(context)
        {
        }

        protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Page> e)
        {
            base.OnElementChanged(e);
        }

        protected override void OnAttachedToWindow()
        {
            base.OnAttachedToWindow();
        }
    }
}
```